# SELECT с шагом PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Предположим, есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table
(
  datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  revenue smallint NOT NULL,
);
```

И я делаю из нее запрос:

```
select datetime,revenue from example_table where datetime between "..." and "..." order BY datetime;
```

Но мне нужно получить, допустим, каждую 5 строку этого запроса. Можно ли это сделать? Без добавления поля `SERIAL`.

Answer (score 2):

Решение в лоб: пронумеровать выборку через `row_number` и достать строки, для которых `row_number` кратен 5.

```
select datetime, revenue from (
    select datetime,revenue, row_number() over() as rn 
    from example_table 
    where datetime between "..." and "..." order BY datetime
) subquery where rn % 5 = 0;
```

А `serial` вам не поможет.